# git ls-remote returns 128 on any repo

Tags: git, gitolite

When using git, `git ls-remote` returns status code `128` while any other commands work flawlessly (push/pull/clone/etc). My repos are being managed with gitolite. I'm getting this error when trying to deploy rails app for the first time. When invoking said command by hand I get standard error like this:

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

If this was permissions/public key issue, I wouldn't be able to push/pull to/from the repo. Why does single `ls-remote` command fail?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was in repo's address. I have used `git://host/repo` address instead of `git@host:repo`. The latter fixed the issue.