# How to check the validity of a  remote git repository URL?

Tags: git, bash, url, curl, github

Within a bash script, what would be the simplest way to verify that a git URL points to a valid git repo and that the script has access to read from it?

Protocols that should be supported are `git@`, `https://`, and `git://`. Curl fails on the `git://` protocol.

```
git@github.com:UserName/Example.git
https://UserName@github.com/UserName/Example.git
git://github.com/UserName/Example.git
```

Note: I'm not asking to check to see if a URL is syntactically correct, I need to verify that a repo exists at the URL location entered from within a bash script.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

As seen in [this issue](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/25#issuecomment-74265878), you can use [git ls-remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html) to test your address.

> If you need to debug the git calls `set GIT_TRACE=1`. eg:

```
env GIT_PROXY_COMMAND=myproxy.sh GIT_TRACE=1 git ls-remote https://...
```

> "`git ls-remote`" is the quickest way I know to test communications with a
> remote repository without actually cloning it. Hence its utility as a test for this
> issue.

You can see it used for detecting an address issue in "[`git ls-remote` returns 128 on any repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564309/git-ls-remote-returns-128-on-any-repo)".

Comment: The Google Code link is broken, msysgit and its issue tracker moved to GitHub. I didn't find the former issue on GitHub, maybe because I'm not sure what I should be searching for.

Comment: @AttilaCsipak Thank you. I have resotred or updated the missing links

Answer (score 54):

Although VonC's answer is correct, here's what I ended up using:

[git ls-remote](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-ls-remote) will return information about a repository, by default this is HEAD, all branches and tags, along with the commit ID for each entry.
e.g.:

```
$ git ls-remote git://github.com/user/repo.git
<commit id>    HEAD
<commit id>    refs/heads/example_branch
<commit id>    refs/heads/master
<commit id>    refs/tags/v1.0.2
<commit id>    refs/tags/v1.0.0
```

`git ls-remote` returns code 0 on success, error code 128 on failure.

If the repo is unreachable, for example, if you don't have permission to view the repository, or if a repository doesn't exist at that location, `git ls-remote` will return:

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

To use this in a bash script, the following will work...

```sh
git ls-remote "$SITE_REPO_URL" > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "[ERROR] Unable to read from '$SITE_REPO_URL'"
    exit 1;
fi
```

(**Note:** The `> /dev/null 2>&1` silences stderr and stdout, so the command won't output anything)

Comment: I'd advise against using `&>-` for portable scripts, as it appears to be a bash extension. In other shells, this syntax won't work as expected. Although there is a similar syntax (`>&- 2>&-`), the functionality is not equivalent -- it will close the file descriptors instead of silently redirecting them, which causes errors in many programs. You can use `> /dev/null 2>&1` instead.

Comment: I added GIT_ASKPASS=true to prevent getting prompted for Username/password on bad url's.

Comment: Is there a way to check without using git?