# What is Error Code 128?

Tags: git

What is git-remote-http error code 128. It happened when I tried to pust to a repo that needed authentication (it never asked for a password.) Is there some central place to find out what error codes mean?

Comment: Going by Linux standards, this would be an abnormal exit due to signal number 0. Which doesn't exist. My guess is this is supposed to mean "abnormal exit for no usual reasons"

Comment: Google? Or here is a [possible related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564309/git-ls-remote-returns-128-on-any-repo)

Comment: I had a similar problem.  git pull and git clone would return code 128.  strace revealed that libnss3.so was segfaulting.  I'm using CentOS 6.5.

Answer (score 7):

`128` is a default fatal error code. It doesn't mean it's necessarily something to do with authentication.

That means you have to read the error message.

See the [source code](https://github.com/git/git/search?l=C&q=exit), and [git documentation](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/api-error-handling).

Answer (score 0):

If you talk of the command return code, it means that the key has been revoked.

You can find the existing codes here for example: http://mazack.org/unix/errno.php

Comment: That link is listing C stdlib [`errno`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages-dev/errno.3.en.html) values, *not* process exit codes.

Answer (score -8):

it's probably because your SSH key has been compromised. Make a new one and add it to your GitHub account.