# GIT Clone with www-data from remote server

Tags: php, git, gitolite

My problem is that I need to perform a clone and a commit from a server which using gitolite to create remote repository.

When I perform a manual clone with www-data user :

> **git clone ssh://git@git-repo.fr/client_1_foo /tmp/client_1_foo**

The project is clone.

But when the same comand is called by my script(PHP) I get an error 128 (SSH error).

**EDIT :** (user executing the script is www-data)
Any idea ?

**gitolite conf :**

```
repo client_1_foo
    RW+ = @client_1_foo_ADMIN @all www-data
    RW = @client_1_foo_DEV Jenkins
    R = daemon
```

Comment: So, as `www-data`, I suppose `ssh -Tv git@git-repo.fr` does work? And what does `ssh -Tvvv git@git-repo.fr` when executed by the user executing your script? Ie. which user is running your PHP?

Comment: Is it possible your PHP script incorrectly set the url? As in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564309/git-ls-remote-returns-128-on-any-repo ?

Comment: Yes that's it ! ':' instead of '/' before repo name ! Merci !

Comment: Excellent. I have added an answer to illustrate that point.

Answer (score 0):

As in "[git ls-remote returns 128 on any repo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6564309/6309)", it is probable the script doesn't build the ssh url properly.

```
git://host:repo (correct)
# instead of 
git@host/repo (incorrect)
```

The [SCP syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14423667/6309) for ssh url usually involve a `~/.ssh/config` file which would resolve the string preceding the '`:`' into a server, user, port and ssh key (as in "[Why can't git resolve the hostname when I push to a valid SSH address?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14134674/6309)").